# Sha1 hash of multiple sha1-hashes -> Secure to identify file?

Tags: cryptography, sha1

Lets say I split a 1G file to 1024 chunks of 1Mb in browser, get an SHA1 of every chunk and save this hash temporary. Finally after hashing all chunks, do an SHA1 of all previous collected SHA1-hashes (do an hash of hashes). Then send this "final"-hash to my server.

Would this hash be secure to identify my file on the server? (Assuming we have an secure connection and sha1 was collision free)

Is it an bad idea to do an hash of multiple hashes?

Comment: Yes but why? Are you protecting against a forgery with the same hash or do you just need to determine if two files are different? For the first case SHA1 is not sufficient for current best practices just use SHA256 or SHA-512. For the second case a single SHA1 is sufficient but it is suggested to move to SHA-256.

Answer (score 4):

I guess your objective is to check integrity of the uploaded file comparing a chekcsum calculated in client side and in server side after completion. Then hashing each chunk, combine them and hashing the result should be enough.

```
//pseudocode
SHA1.digest ( 
    SHA1.digest(chunk 1) + SHA1.digest(chunk 2) + ... + SHA1.digest(chunk n))
```

But note you can perform an incremental SHA1 hash on the complete file adding  each chunk to the calculation. In this way the result is the same that hashing the complete file in one step and you do not need to combine temporal data

```
    SHA1.update(chunk 1)
    SHA1.update(chunk 2)
    ...
    SHA1.update(chunk n)
    SHA1.digest ()
```

Consider also to move to sha256 as shown in the comments, but probably for this purpose SHA1 would be adequate

Comment: how can I update sha1 with new chunk of data in Browser? As far as I know there is no update method on crypto.subtle in any modern browser. Did you has in mind any alternatives?

Comment: @MarcinPevik there is no `update` method in WebCryptoApi. Maybe you can use an alternative javascript library like forge. see https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#sha1

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Assuming SHA-1 is [collision free](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html), for two different files at least one of this hashes differ from each other. So the "final" hashes will also differ.

In general, hashing hashes does not improve security. If you want more security use SHA-256.

Comment: About your link, if you read it you will find that substantial computer power was needed: 6,500 years of CPU computation to complete the attack first phase plus
110 years of GPU computation to complete the second phase. Is this a viable attack? No. That attack kind-of proves that for common usage SHA1 is indeed collision safe.

Comment: I have read this. SHA1 is theoretically broken for some years and now they constructed a collision. So it is broken.
The time expense is maybe a problem for you and me, but some guys have quite a lot of CPUs and GPUs. So you should not use SHA1 for any new project, if you want security. If you don't care about security and just want a fingerprint for internal use you can use SHA1, since you will not run into a collision by accident.

Comment: The use of SHA1 depends on the security needs. It is considered broken for authentication but not for file uniqueness such as Git uses. Sure SHA-256 is generally a better choice than SHA1 but SHA1 is still valid for many usages. If you are protecting against an attacker that can expend 6,500 CPU years per hash you have a larger problem and should be more concerned about [rubber-hose cryptanalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis).

Comment: In general the"SHA-1 is broken" is a "[chicken little](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henny_Penny)" issue, that chicken may be right if we wait long enough.

Comment: To bring this to an end: Summing up my answer: yes it works, but if you are concerned about security use sha256, just as in your comment. Your point is only about the attack shown in the link. This attack only proves that it is possible to create a collision. It does not prove that it takes at least that long. Maybe someone has a faster algorithm.

Comment: I address the attack in the link because that is the lead in the answer.